# aws-sdk で instance_profile から Role を取得する方法

Tags: aws, aws-iam, aws-sdk

EC2 に付与されてる Role をプログラムで取得したいだけなのですがどうしてもやり方がわかりません

ec2 の attribute は取得できたのですが
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/EC2/Types/Instance.html
その中に role という項目はなく
iam_instance_profile という属性はありました

AWS コンソールで Role のページを開くと 
インスタンスプロファイル ARN
というのが表示されるのでこれがそのまま Role と対応してる？と思うのですが

インスタンスプロファイル ARN から Role 名を取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか

aws-sdk-ruby を使うつもりなのですができるのであれば言語は何でもいいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CLI コマンド から取得する方法があるようです。

参考:
[get-instance-profile — AWS CLI 1.16.262 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-instance-profile.html)

**実行例**

```
$ aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name ExampleInstanceProfile
```

**出力結果**

```js
{
    "InstanceProfile": {
        "InstanceProfileId": "AID2MAB8DPLSRHEXAMPLE",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": "<URL-encoded-JSON>",
                "RoleId": "AIDGPMS9RO4H3FEXAMPLE",
                "CreateDate": "2013-01-09T06:33:26Z",
                "RoleName": "Test-Role",
                "Path": "/",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::336924118301:role/Test-Role"
            }
        ],
        "CreateDate": "2013-06-12T23:52:02Z",
        "InstanceProfileName": "ExampleInstanceProfile",
        "Path": "/",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::336924118301:instance-profile/ExampleInstanceProfile"
    }
}
```

Comment: aws cli を使うのは考えに至りませんでした…　コマンドにあるならaws-sdkにもありそうですが　もう少し調べてダメそうならexecでコマンド呼び出して取得させていただきます

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/IAM/Client.html#get_instance_profile-instance_method でできそうです　EC2やRole,InstanceProfileクラスのメソッドばかり見てたのでIAMクラスのメソッドをみるべきだったようです